# Testbench clk not advancing

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, modelsim

All my testbench is trying to do is verify whether or not the LED signal went high, but on Modelsim when I try and simulate it, the clock doesn't even start, but it initializes to zero. I can also step through my design so I don't appear to have an infinite loop or anything like that. Is there anything obviously wrong here, especially with regards to clock initialization and generation?

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
 
module fir_filter_tb();
 reg clk, reset_n;
 reg led;

top top_level (
    .clk(clk),
    .reset_n(reset_n),
    .led(led)
    );
    
    initial
     begin
     $display($time, " << Starting the Simulation >>");
     clk = 1'b0; // at time 0
     reset_n = 0; // reset is active
     led = 0; // output is low
     #10 reset_n = 1'b1; // at time 20 release reset
     end
    
    always #10 clk = ~clk;

    always
    begin
         if (led ==  1'b1) begin
             $write($time, "Filter Successful");
         end else begin
             $write($time, "bleh you suck");
         end
    end
endmodule : fir_filter_tb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `always` block with `led` in it.  Since there is no timing control, it prevents time from advancing (time remains stuck at 0).  It creates an infinite zero-time loop.

One way to fix it is to use:

```
always @*
```

This will only trigger the block when `led` changes.